# Libgdx attaching texture to Box2d body

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d

I'm trying to attach my sprite to my Box2D body in LibGDX:

```
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {

    float positionXToDraw = TheCavern.getUnitXFromBox2D(body.getPosition().x - radius);
    float positionYToDraw = TheCavern.getUnitYFromBox2D(body.getPosition().y - radius);

    float width = (radius * 2) * 20; 
    float height = (radius * 2) * 20;

    /*
         (radius * 2) -> Diameter (ImageWidth in libgdx);  
         * 20 -> Coordinates from Box2D to libGDX
    */

    batch.draw(texture, positionXToDraw, positionYToDraw, width, height);
}
```

At first all seems to work good, when the body is static the sprite fits correctly the shape of the body.

[image: Static Body]

But once the body is set to dynamic and it is affected by gravity, the texture falls faster than the body.

[image]

The higher amount of meters it falls, the higher the distance between the body and the sprite.

Comment: Can there might be a possibility in your game logic that speed of word step is different than calling this draw method? If yes, then its normal.